# How to recursive mark ROS_NOBUILD with rosmake --mark-installed?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been testing ROS in openSUSE (successfully so far) using a system wide installation (for multiple users). Since this is a system installation, it is not writable by regular users. As such, to prevent built packages from being built again, I am using the --mark-installed option (to add a ROS_NOBUILD file upon completion).

The problem is that the ROS_NOBUILD file is added only to the packages I pass as argument to the rosmake command. All dependencies that are built do not get the --mark-installed option by default, which is my desired behavior. Is there a way to make it happen?

Otherwise I have to either rosmake each and every needed package, or add the ROS_NOBUILD by hand to every built package.

Thanks and regards,

Hugo Costelha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10817/how-to-recursive-mark-ros_nobuild-with-rosmake---mark-installed-?/) by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may want to look at the rosprotect tool if you wish to mark a installation tree as no build:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros_python_tools/rosprotect

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-09**:
Yeah, the current design is to allow symmetry with the --unmark-installed option.  In the unmark case the specifics do matter.

**Comment by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on 2011-08-05**:
Ok, thanks. Nevertheless, I think that marking (all) successful builds with ROS_NOBUILD when using rosmake would be an interesting/desired feature.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-04**:
The python tools in eros' diamondback tag will still work for electric, I've just held off tagging it while electric is beta as there's a fair few things I need to do in other areas.

**Comment by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on 2011-08-04**:
Thanks for your answer but I am testing with the electric distribution, and eros_python_tools only as a tag for diamondback. Nevertheless, I think that making the switch recursive would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `rosmake --mark-installed STACK_NAMES` with stack names as the target or if you want all packages in the system installation `rosmake -a --mark-installed`.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on 2011-08-09**:
For now I will use the "-a --mark-installed", as it gets the job done for all packages. Thanks for the tip.